# pinging and tracerouting from WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, network-programming

Am I able to do `ping` or `tracert` or basically any network based command from my wp7 to any server?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [System.Net.NetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ew4thdx%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) documentation, there's no support for Ping or Trace routing on Windows Phone or for Silverlight in general.

However, you could open a [direct socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202874%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), and write the PING / network command yourself.