# How to ping in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, network-programming, network-protocols, ping, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have a project based on windows Phone 7.5, which contains a module to ping remote devices (in the same subnet or internet). I tried to perform an  echo request and reply on port 7. but reply does not comes back, rather, an NullReferenceException occurs when I try to access `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Buffer`. I also tried creating ICMP type packets in app, but no luck.

As far as my understanding goes, icmp packets are not allowed to perform ping. however, from desktop, the phone can be pinged if ip address of phone is known.

I have checked many applications on marketplace (like Console WP7 Lite, TestMyNet), those can perform ping by sending icmp packets and can also access Round trip time of ping operation.

I am wondering how those applications can ping to remote (accessible) devices, when windows phone sockets does not allow icmp packets.

Can anyone help me. 
Thanx for help in advance

Comment: If you found applications that will do this, have you reached out to those developers to see if they would help?

Comment: No... I cant reach them... And even if i reach somehow, why they would tell me such secret...

Comment: Many developers share techniques.  What do you think this website is?  How to ping a host is not a secret.  No, I don't know how to do it, but if I saw an app that did what I was looking to do, I would reach out to that developer and ask him how he did it.

Comment: Have you tried searching SO? [Some easy search showed this to me...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273805/pinging-and-tracerouting-from-wp7)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure these apps can ping local network? For example can they ping WP Wifi interface's  gateway or the WP Wifi interface itself? Or can the only ping hosts on Internet? I tried both apps mentioned by you, and even more and they ping everything except local network. That is why i was convincend that they use external server to perform pings and roound-trip is only calculated or estimated somehow.

Piotr Wojtowicz

Comment: yeah i m sure, they are actually not pinging using ICMP packets, because ICMP is not a supported option in ProtocolType Enum of Sockets. If they are doing this, they they will obviously be using cracks and hacks.